# Intel SGX cannot find sgxsdk/environment

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, intel, sgx

I'm working with Intel SGX on Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to run some SampleApps. However I get errors like: `./app: error while loading shared libraries: libsgx_urts.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I checked on the internet and people say I need to do `source /opt/intel/sgxsdk/environment`. But I don't have /environment in sgxsdk. `-bash: /opt/intel/sgxsdk/environment: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You must verify that you've installed the Intel SGX sdk. Either from the [github repo](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx) or directly downloading the binary from [the intel repo](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/).

If you're using the github repo, you should follow the build process then the installation of the sdk. The steps are the following on ubuntu 20.04 for example:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential ocaml ocamlbuild automake autoconf libtool wget python-is-python3 libssl-dev git cmake perl

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev debhelper cmake reprepro unzip pkgconf libboost-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev protobuf-c-compiler libprotobuf-c-dev lsb-release libsystemd0

git clone https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx.git
cd linux-sgx && make preparation

sudo cp external/toolset/{current_distr}/* /usr/local/bin
which ar as ld objcopy objdump ranlib

# build
make sdk

# install 
sudo apt-get install build-essential python
cd linux/installer/bin
./sgx_linux_x64_sdk_${version}.bin

# and finally source 
source ${sgx-sdk-install-path}/environment
```